# How to pass 'page' dynamically to exportOptions>modifier in Datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

For exporting the table data in excel file I wrote below code.

```
"buttons": [
        {
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            text: 'Excel Export',
            filename: function () { return 'AllLists_' + time; },
            exportOptions: {
                columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                modifier: {
                    page: 'current',                        
                }
            },
        }
    ],
```

Here at line `page: 'all/current'`want to select dynamically, so for this I write below code.

```
<select class="form-control" id="selectDataOption">
     <option value="current">Current page</option>
     <option value="all">Entire table</option>
</select>
```

I've used below code for selecting the dropdown dynamically -

```
$("#exportExcelbtn").on("click", function () {
  dt_tblOutForApproval.buttons.exportData({
    modifier: {
        page: function () {
            return ($("#selectDataOption").children("option").filter(":selected").val());
        }
     }
   });
});
```

But this doesn't help. can anyone help me better solution or if am i missing something in my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`dt_tblOutForApproval.buttons.exportData()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/buttons.exportData()) is not a function that exports data to file, but **a function that returns data**.

As for your question, there're two possible ways to do that :

1. Because the DataTable doesn't allow us to initialize the options again, we could drop the raw table and create a new table. But that's not an efficient way.
2. The second approach is to **remove the old 'Excel Export' button and create a new button according to current mode dynamically**. Since there will be a state of two modes (current & all), I **create a `ExcelExportManager()` to manage current mode (state)**:

   ```
   // dt is an object created by `$('#example').DataTable({})`
   function ExcelExportManager(dt){ 
       function _createExportButtonOpt(pageOpt="current"){
           return {
               extend: 'excelHtml5',
               text: 'export ' + pageOpt,
               name : pageOpt,        // button name
               filename: function () { return 'AllLists_' + time; },
               exportOptions: {
                   //columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                   modifier:{ page: pageOpt }, 
               },
           };
       };

       function _setModeAsCurrent(){
           var current= dt.button().remove(0, "current:name");
           var current= dt.button().remove(0, "all:name");
           var current= dt.button().add(0, _createExportButtonOpt("current"));
       }

       function _setModeAsAll(){
           var current= dt.button().remove(0, "current:name"); 
           var current= dt.button().remove(0, "all:name");
           var current= dt.button().add(0, _createExportButtonOpt("all"));
       }

       var mode = "current";  // initial value
       Object.defineProperty(this,"exportMode",{
           get:function(){ return pageMode; },
           set:function(value){
               switch(value.toLowerCase()){
                   case "current":
                       _setModeAsCurrent();
                       break;
                   case "all":
                       _setModeAsAll();
                       break;
                   default:
                       throw new Error("unsupported export mode");
               }
               mode = value;
           },
       });
   };

   // create an instance
   var excelManager = new ExcelExportManager(dt_tblOutForApproval);
   ```

   In this way, when we want to change the mode, we could simply **set the `excelManager.exportMode`property** :

   ```
   // a function that get current option selected by user
   function getExportMode(){
       return exportOption=$("#selectDataOption").children("option")
           .filter(":selected")
           .val();
   }
    // initialize 
   excelManager.exportMode = getExportMode();
   // on change
   $("#selectDataOption").change(function() { excelManager.exportMode = getExportMode(); });
   ```

**A demo:**

[image]

**To play online, click the Run code snippet**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.18/b-1.5.6/b-html5-1.5.6/datatables.min.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.18/b-1.5.6/b-html5-1.5.6/datatables.min.js"></script>

    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                    <td>System Architect</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                    <td>$3,120</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                    <td>Director</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>63</td>
                    <td>2011/07/25</td>
                    <td>$5,300</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                    <td>
                        <123414124124.null@domain.com>
                    </td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>66</td>
                    <td>2009/01/12</td>
                    <td>$4,800</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                    <td>
                        <123414124124.null@domain.com>
                    </td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>66</td>
                    <td>2009/01/12</td>
                    <td>$4,800</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                    <td>
                        <123414124124.null@domain.com>
                    </td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>66</td>
                    <td>2009/01/12</td>
                    <td>$4,800</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                    <td>
                        <123414124124.null@domain.com>
                    </td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>66</td>
                    <td>2009/01/12</td>
                    <td>$4,800</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                    <td>
                        <123414124124.null@domain.com>
                    </td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>66</td>
                    <td>2009/01/12</td>
                    <td>$4,800</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                    <td>
                        <123414124124.null@domain.com>
                    </td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>66</td>
                    <td>2009/01/12</td>
                    <td>$4,800</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <select class="form-control" id="selectDataOption">
        <option value="current">Current page</option>
        <option value="all">Entire table</option>
    </select>
</body>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var time = new Date();
        var dt_tblOutForApproval = $('#example').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bftrip',
            paging: true,
            pageLength: 5,
            buttons: [ ]
        });

        // dt is an object created by `$('#example').DataTable({})`
        function ExcelExportManager(dt){ 
            function _createExportButtonOpt(pageOpt="current"){
                return {
                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                    text: 'export ' + pageOpt,
                    name : pageOpt,        // button name
                    filename: function () { return 'AllLists_' + time; },
                    exportOptions: {
                        //columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                        modifier:{ page: pageOpt }, 
                    },
                };
            };

            function _setModeAsCurrent(){
                var current= dt.button().remove(0, "current:name");
                var current= dt.button().remove(0, "all:name");
                var current= dt.button().add(0, _createExportButtonOpt("current"));
            }

            function _setModeAsAll(){
                var current= dt.button().remove(0, "current:name"); 
                var current= dt.button().remove(0, "all:name");
                var current= dt.button().add(0, _createExportButtonOpt("all"));
            }

            var mode = "current";  // initial value
            Object.defineProperty(this,"exportMode",{
                get:function(){ return pageMode; },
                set:function(value){
                    switch(value.toLowerCase()){
                        case "current":
                            _setModeAsCurrent();
                            break;
                        case "all":
                            _setModeAsAll();
                            break;
                        default:
                            throw new Error("unsupported export mode");
                    }
                    mode = value;
                },
            });
        };

        function getExportMode(){
            return exportOption=$("#selectDataOption").children("option")
                .filter(":selected")
                .val();
        }
        var excelManager = new ExcelExportManager(dt_tblOutForApproval);
        // initialize 
        excelManager.exportMode = getExportMode();
        // on change
        $("#selectDataOption").change(function() { excelManager.exportMode = getExportMode(); });
    });
</script>

</html>
```